# Compile errors with open addressed hash table in C++ using vectors and templates, "template argument deduction/ substitution failed"

Tags: c++, vector, hashtable

I'm trying to create an open addressed hash table in C++, using vectors and templates for class.
On compiling with a tester file I am getting the following errors, I've tried different methods of doing this, all of which seem to output messages similar to the following, consistently after most errors I seem to get "note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: In file included from test1.cpp ...". I'm not sure how to work arround this

Current Main Compile Error:

```
 HashTable.h:116:20: error: ‘class HashNode<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>’ has no member named ‘getNext’; did you mean ‘getKey’?
     while (current.getNext() != NULL)
            ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
            getKey
HashTable.h:118:25: error: ‘class HashNode<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>’ has no member named ‘getNext’; did you mean ‘getKey’?
       current = current.getNext();
                 ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
                 getKey


HashTable.h:121:13: error: ‘class HashNode<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>’ has no member named ‘setNext’
     current.setNext(newNode);
     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
HashTable.h: In instantiation of ‘ValueType HashTable<KeyType, ValueType>::getValue(KeyType) [with KeyType = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; ValueType = int]’:
test1.cpp:46:26:   required from here
HashTable.h:88:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(HashNode<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)’
     for(HashNode<KeyType, ValueType> h : n)
```

```
    #ifndef MY_HASH_TABLE
    #define MY_HASH_TABLE

    #include "HashNode.h"
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

     template <class KeyType, class ValueType>
        class HashTable {
          typedef vector <HashNode<KeyType,ValueType> > Table;
          Table *table; // size of table (# of buckets) is stored in the Table data structure
          uint num;   // number of entries stored in the HashTable;

                template <class KeyType, class ValueType>
                void HashTable<KeyType, ValueType>::insert(KeyType key, ValueType value)
                {
                  uint index = hash_function(key);
                  HashNode<KeyType, ValueType> newNode;
                  newNode.assign(key, value);
                  if (table.at(index) != NULL)
                  {
                    HashNode<KeyType, ValueType> current;
                    current = table->at(index);

                while (current.getNext() != NULL)
                {
                  current = current.getNext();
                }

                current.setNext(newNode);
              }
              else
              {
                table->at(index) = newNode;
              }
              num++;
            }

        template <class KeyType, class ValueType>
        int HashTable<KeyType, ValueType>::hash_function(KeyType key)
        {
          uint hash = key % size();
          return hash;
        }

        template <class KeyType, class ValueType>
        int HashTable<KeyType,ValueType>::size() {
          return table->size();
        }

    template <class KeyType, class ValueType>
    void HashTable<KeyType, ValueType>::erase(KeyType key)
    {

        uint hashValue = hash_function(key);
        HashNode<KeyType, ValueType> l = table->at(hashValue);
        for(auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it){
          if (it->getKey() == key) {
            l.erase(it);
            break;
          }
        }

        num--;
    }

    template <class KeyType, class ValueType>
    ValueType HashTable<KeyType, ValueType>::getValue(KeyType key)
    {
      try
      {
        uint hashValue = hash_function(key);
        HashNode<KeyType, ValueType> n = table->at(hashValue);
        for(HashNode<KeyType, ValueType> h : n)
        {
          if(h.getKey() == key)
          {
            return h.getValue();
          }
        }

        throw KEY_NOT_FOUND;
      }
      catch(HashTableError)
      {
        cout<< "Error! KEY_NOT_FOUND";
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Code for HashNode.h

```
#ifndef MY_HASH_NODE
#define MY_HASH_NODE

using namespace std;

template <class KeyType, class ValueType>
class HashNode 
{
  KeyType key;     // The hash node's key
  ValueType value; // The key's associated datatemplate argument deduction/substitution failed

  /* extend if necessary */

public:
  HashNode(KeyType key, ValueType value) 
  {
    this-> value = value;
    this-> key = key;
  }  // constructor

  HashNode(){}

  KeyType getKey() { return key; }
  ValueType getValue() { return value; }
  void assign(KeyType key, ValueType value); 

  // extend if necessary
};

template <class KeyType, class ValueType>
void HashNode<KeyType, ValueType>::assign(KeyType key, ValueType value)
{
  this-> value = value; 
  this-> key = key; 
}


/* 
   Implement the constructor, the assign method 
   and any methods that you may additionally need for the HashTable to work.
*/

#endif
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` -- A side note -- do not put this in a header file.

Comment: can we please see the code for `#include "HashNode.h"`

Comment: Added code for include HashNode.h, and using namespace std is a requirement for this assignment unfortunately

Comment: from the code shown for `HashNode.h`, it actually has no functions named `getNext()`  which is conveyed by the error message *HashTable.h:116:20: error: ‘class HashNode ....   has no member named ‘getNext’; did you mean ‘getKey’? ... * . you will have to implement the getNext() function.